# Stop BI-Excel Add-In (Jedox) from recalculating when values loaded into ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, business-intelligence, jedox

I get values in a `ComboBox` in a `UserForm`:

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
ComboBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A1:A4").Value
End Sub
```

The values in `A1:A4` are `Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4`

I use a BI-Tool called [Jedox](https://knowledgebase.jedox.com/knowledgebase/quickstart-jedox-excel-add-in/) as Excel AddIn. The tool inserts values from a BI-Cube into my Excel spreadsheet using specific formulas in the cells.

Once I click the `Userform` to load it also triggers the BI-Tool (Jedox) to re-calculate all values in every sheet. Is there a way to avoid this re-calculating?

Keep in mind that once the filter is selected the re-calculating should be done because the filter should trigger an update of the values.

Comment: Turn off auto-calculation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how about:

```
Application.Calculation = xlmanual
```

your code

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Comment: There may be other things to do to help, have a search for q & a on here with words like "slow code" or speed up code" etc